# Would an inter-dimensional being need to eat?

Tags: biology, creature-design, spacetime-dimensions, shapeshifters, dimensions

Would a being that could enter any space in any time, assume any shape, need sustenance or a source of energy to stay alive or does their very existence as inter-dimensional beings imply that they are in fact immortal?

Comment: Can they get tired, in any way shape or form? Depending on that you have your answer.

Comment: We don’t currently know of any inter dimensional beings, so this seems like a classic “whatever you feel like”

Comment: Being immortal is different than needing a source of energy or sustenance. This aside, it's impossible to tell, it's your creature after all and could be "powered" by magic, making sustenance all unneeded in the traditional sense ^^. Or... It could not, we don't know. Perhaps if you added more details on how this creature works, we could have answers that help you define it.

Comment: VTC Opinion-Based. Per the [help/dont-ask], "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question." It's your world - do you want them to eat or not? Make a choice, both choices are equally valid (from the same HC page, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid."). What problem are you trying to overcome? Why is this question an issue? What's stopping you from simply choosing one?

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact (et al) I VTR, this, because there are no science tags or reality-checks involved. I don't see the issue with opinion-based in this case, any creature design question is opinion based, open ended and hypothetical. There are questions about chimaera's and merfolk on WB, these don't get closed within a few hours.  Anything you can imagine, with these creatures..  so why would the word "dimension" be any hurdle to give a decent *creature-design* answer ?

Comment: @Goodies SE doesn't work that way. It has rules. Some are ours. Some are Stack Exchange's. A proper question would explain the specific problem the OP has trying to develop their creature, including conditions and limitations, and explaining their goals and expectations. As much as you might not like it, Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum - people are expected to ask for help solving specific problems. To put it simply, this question is inviting a discussion with no evidence that any answer can be objectively chosen as a best answer.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact +1 thanks for your response on my remark.. maybe it's better to discuss this on Meta, but I do acknowledge there is a close reason here. If I would vtc this question: it needs more clarification. Not because of "opinion based". I think you can't edit above question to solve that. An answer on this question will always be opinion based, because there exists no science-based explanation for "interdimensional". The general SE rules talk about fact-based answers. There exist WB topics that have such answers.. but most answers here are fantasy to help out.

Comment: @Goodies You're behind the curve (e.g., [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5991/40609)). What "opinion-based" means has been debated since 2014. The kinda-consensus is, "if the only way the OP can choose a best answer is based on his/her opinion, the Q is opinion-based." The problem is that "opinion based" is a network-wide VTC. We're stuck with it and there isn't an easy way to train new users as to how to use it (c.f. our comments) nor a way to police people to simply ignore it (there's always more new users). (\*Continued\*)

Comment: @Goodies ... My [last meta post on the issue](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8398/40609) is germaine to this particular question... but few people actually search meta.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact I'm reinventing the wheel here, apparently.. thanks for the links , I'll study it..

Answer (score 2):

**Up to Your Imagination**

Your question is in the same territory as "Time travel exists, can I become my own grandfather?" If you give some parameters for how your time travel works, we can help you with making it self-consistent.

However if no other parameters of time travel are given, the answer is up to you. You get to decide the rules of your time travel and whether it is possible to create time paradoxes.

For your interdimensional beings, you have given only a few parameters, so you get to decide what the rules are.

Perhaps these "interdimensional beings" exist outside of our universe. They can look at the entire history of our universe all at once and hop into any time and place they want. Their larger universe has its own space and time dimensions, relative to which they are finite and mortal, and they need to eat so-called interdimensional food.

This interdimensional food might be as simple as eight-dimensional chicken sandwiches. Or it might be as elaborate as eating the universes that splinter off when time travellers cause a split in the timeline. They might eat the souls of sapient creatures. They might eat the *absence of souls* which in fact creates souls from our point of view. Or they might have a form of food so ineffably unlike anything in our universe that is silly to try and describe it.

On the other extreme,  perhaps the interdimensional beings exist outside **the universe**. Things that exist outside **the universe** are not subject to its laws of course, and are in god territory. It is up to you what powers your gods have.

Answer (score 0):

I think obviously they need some sort of energy supply, they are "moving". I imagine it takes energy to move through space, or time, and it takes energy to assume some other shape, or to do anything, really. It takes energy for us to just **think**, the brain consumes something like 25% of our calories.

Just traveling through time does not imply immortality; if I could travel through time I would still expect to be able to get sick, to be injured or poisoned and to die.

The being must have some **local** time, local to its body, or it can't have any sense of past or future, things done or things to be done.

Even photons that travel for billions of years between Galaxies are destroyed by interaction with other matter, including our own retinas or cameras behind telescopes.

So yes, some sort of energy supply is likely necessary for this being in order for it to think, remember, or take actions. "Eating" may not be the word for it, plants absorb energy without really "eating", and your being that can take any shape may choose to recharge near stars and absorb the light energy directly, or may be able to survive on high infrared energy (heat) alone. So they may chill the room if they "feed".

But yes, I'd expect them to need to consume energy if they are to be at all physically plausible.